# Insert node binary tree

Tags: f#, tree

I have this tree node :

```
type Tree<'T when 'T: comparison> = 
| Empty 
| Node of 'T * Tree<'T> * Tree<'T>
```

but I cant find out a good insert function.

I don't want to do a interactive program, the input should be a list that is inserted to the tree.

Comment: Did you look here? http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Advanced_Data_Structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the tree to be balanced then you can use:

```
let rec insert value = function
| Empty -> Node(value, Empty, Empty)
| Node(v, left, right) when value < v -> Node(v, insert value left, right)
| Node(v, left, right) when value > v -> Node(v, left, insert value right)
| Node(_, _, _) as n -> n
```

You can insert a list of values into a tree with:

```
let insertAll list tree = List.fold (fun t e -> insert e t) tree list
```

Comment: is there any good way to represent the tree so its easy to se if the operation worked and how can I do it so that it works to add a whole list of integers at the same time?

Comment: @user1838768 - I'm not sure what you mean by 'represent the tree' - do you want to convert to a string? I've updated the answer with a function to add a list.